# Unzip file through file transfer activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, import

I have an automation that runs daily. It is based on a file drop when file.zip is uploaded into the import folder of the FTP. I then use a file transfer activity to unzip the file, if I am not mistaken it then puts the unzipped file on the Safehouse. In the next step I import the file from the safehouse into a data extension. But since this automation runs daily, there are multiple unzipped files on the Safehouse. Therefore the oldest file is uploaded in the data extension, not the newest one. I tested this by importing the csv manually from my own computer. The numbers were completely different.

So, my question is: is it possible to unzip in the import folder of the FTP? If not, how can I make sure the latest file is chosen on the Safehouse? Am I required to timestamp it?

Thanks!